# how to create TEMPORARY table in laravel, insert record and retrive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello friends I trying for create temp table in laravel and insert record and retrieve that record from temp table and then drop table.

But my temp table is not create
 `DB::raw("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp(temp_id VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn1 VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn2 VARCHAR(100),tempcolumn3 VARCHAR(100)) ;`

My table structure like

Stud_table
Stud_id       | stud_name|class_type_id | exam_name_id
Stud001     |xyz               |class0001       |pri_0001
Stud002     |abcd            |class0002       |sec_0001
Stud003     |cgdd            |class0003       |sup_0001
Stud004     |ghgf             |class0001       |pri_0001

Here exam_name depend on class_type_id  if class type

"primary" then retrive data from   "primary_exam_table"

"Secondary" then retrive data from "Secondary_exam_table"

"Super" then retrive data from "Super_exam_table"

Tbl_class_type

class_type_id|class_name

---

class0001     |primary

---

class0002     |Secondary

---

class0003     |Super

---

---

primary_exam_table

primary_exam_id | priexam_name
Pri0001                 |primaryexam

---

Secondary_exam_table

Secondary_exam_id | secexam_name
sec0001                 |secondaryyexam

---

Super_exam_table

Super_exam_id | superexam_name
Sup0001                 |superexam

---

I want to search and sort  record   stud_name,class_name,exam_name 
I retrive record in array and i want insert that record in temporary table that make my search and sort easy.
Thats why i want temporary table

Comment: what is idea behind? is it for unitest?

Comment: MySQL, unfortunately, won't let you create any temporary tables. However, if there was a good reason why you need it, please elaborate the problem and some alternatives can then certainly be thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I use MySQL. It must be worked:

Creating table:

```
 Schema::create('real_temp', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('airline');
  $table->timestamps();
  $table->temporary();
});
```

then operations with table like

```
DB::table('real_temp')->insert([...]);
```

then

```
Schema::drop('real_temp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql temporary table only exists in current MySQL connection, so your SQL is correct.you just can't see or get results from another connection.

The best way to use temporary table is:

1. create temporary table
2. deal logic using that temporary table.
3. get logic results, but not from the temporary table.

Answer (score -1):

Do you write "TEMPORARY" in your SQL query? Because "TEMPORARY" is Not a mysql keyword, so that wouldnt work.
What error message did you got?

Comment: www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm   i take reference from this link to create temp table.